# After modifying a doc file, office has issues opening it for editing

Tags: java, ms-word, ms-office

So after modifying a file in java, code taken from Naresh in: http://www.coderanch.com/t/534754/java/java/Editing-pdf-word-content-text

I've noticed something, while it works flawlessly, Office is now telling me:

"Office has detected a problem with this file. Editing it may harm your computer"

Any way to fix this? I'm opening the file, replacing a text, and then saving a copy of the file.

Comment: Offhand, I'd say there's a bug in the Java code.

Comment: So it's not that modified documents will always look suspicious, correct?

Comment: I don't pretend to know how Office is triggering that message, but I'd hope not. I'd suggest contacting the authors of that library and reporting this as a possible bug; they might be able to advise you.